# Can CRUD operations be performed on Oracle Views

Tags: oracle, view, crud, updatable-views

I know this is kind of vague, but I'm new to views and am trying to learn what they're capable of.

Let's say I create a view created by complex queries using a combination of tables.  If I tried to edit a record in the view, would the view be smart enough to go backwards through the logic which created the view and edit the correct value in the correct table?

Is editing a value even allowed in a view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm

See the section called: "Notes on Updatable Views"

Note that you can ALWAYS create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on any view to make it updatable (you supply the logic).

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look possible based on their requirements.  Thanks!